# Autoconf Standardized Configure Target Namings

Tags: architecture, autotools, configure, autoconf, prefix

Is there a way to automatically lookup the standardized target namings such as `i686-pc-linux-gnu` I typically want to feed as argument to the configure flag `--exec-prefix` in platform-specific builds? I've seen `./configure && make && make install`s automatically install stuff in `$PREFIX/i686-pc-linux-gnu` without specifying `--exec-prefix` so some automated naming logic must exist under hood in autoconf.

Comment: Are you looking for `config.guess`?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I'm reposting this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The autotools generated file `config.guess` is the answer.